# UIView's initWithFrame not working?

Tags: iphone

i set my view controller to the particular view through Interfacebuilder.
but initWithFrame is not calling , but drawRect is being called?when i put break point?

Answer (score 17):

Right, because it's not guaranteed that `initWithFrame:` will be called when unarchiving the xib.  Try using `awakeFromNib` or `viewWillLoad` or `viewDidLoad`.  Which one you choose will mainly depend on at what stage during the display process you need to insert your code.

Also, check out the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433539/initwithframe-not-called-but-awakefromnib-is).

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html - `initWithFrame:` *is not called when your view objects are subsequently loaded from the nib file. Objects in a nib file are reconstituted and then initialized using their `initWithCoder:` method, which modifies the attributes of the view to match the attributes stored in the nib file.*