# NSView initialization: -init: vs. -awakeFromNib:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface, nsview

I have a simple class `MyView` inherited from `NSView` and instance variable `NSImage * image;` in it. Class functionality is to draw image on the view.

However, in `-drawRect:` image instance always equal `nil`, if it was initialized in `-init:` function and not `nil` if it was initialized in `-awakeFromNib:`. Log shows both `-init:` and `-awakeFromNib:` functions are called only once.

Does `-awakeFromNib:` reinitialize GUI component by default?

Answer (score 9):

No. There is no default implementation for `awakeFromNib`.

Your problem is that you're overriding the wrong initialization method. An `NSView`'s [designated initializer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH33-SW2) is `initWithFrame:`. Your subclass's plain `init` never gets called, and that is why your `image` ivar doesn't point to anything.

You can initialize that ivar in either `awakeFromNib` or `initWithFrame:`. It makes no difference. The former is called after the latter, and it is provided as a point where you can insert initialization code that needs to interact with other objects in your nib (via your `IBOutlets`).

Comment: Though in some cases `-initWithFrame` [is not called at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433539/initwithframe-not-called-but-awakefromnib-is).

Comment: There is only _one_ case when your custom subclass's `initWithFrame:` will not be called at all: when it inherits from another `NSView` subclass which exists in an IB palette (e.g., `NSImageView`), and you create the instance of your custom subclass by changing the class in the Identity inspector. In that case, the AppKit subclass's `initWithFrame:` _will_ be called, and your custom subclass's will get `initWithCoder:` before `awakeFromNib`. If you create your view instance using the "Custom View" object in IB, your view's `initWithFrame:` does indeed get called.

Comment: I created a _Custom View_ and set my `NSView` subclass as its class in Identity Inspector. I didn't get a call to `initWithFrame:`; `awakeFromNib` gets called though. This is on macOS 10.14.1, with Xcode 10.1.

Comment: In a similar situation as that described by @legends2k, my NSView subclass also didn't get a call to `initWithFrame`; it _did_ get a call to `initWithCoder`.